# Combine multiple datatables into single result in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I have four tables that are passed to the page in the context. Each of the 4 tables are connected by an Id column. I would like to display a page with a table that combines columns from each of the 4 tables. I would also like to sort or search data and display the results based on 1 or all tables (for example, if table 2 contains the column "Name", then the search results should show only rows that match that name)

```
   public IList<AllTables> AllTableData {get;set;}

   public async Task OnGetAsync(
       string sortOrder,
       string queryFilter,
       string searchString)
   {
   //setting sort and search Params
   //......

   IQueryable<Table1> table1= _context.Table1.Select(f => f);
   IQueryable<Table2> table2= _context.Table2.Select(f => f);
   IQueryable<Table3> table3= _context.Table3.Select(f => f);
   IQueryable<Table4> table4= _context.Table4.Select(f => f);

   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
   {
      // e.g. table1= table1.Where(s => s.Id.ToString() == searchString);
    }

    //Example for sorting
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "Id":
           table1= table1.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
           break;
        case "Name":
           table2= table2.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
           break;
    }

    //How do I combine all four tables
    AllTableData = await (Join Tables 1-4).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }
```

I have tried to create a new class such as follows

```
  public Class AllTables
  {
     public Table1 Table1{get;set;}
     public Table2 Table2{get;set;}
     public Table3 Table3{get;set;}
     public Table4 Table4{get;set;}
  }
```

And then combining the data like this

```
  AllTableData= await table1
            .Select(f=>new AllTables(
                f,
                table2.Where(g => g.Id== f.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                table3.Where(h => h.Id== f.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                table4.Where(i => i.Id== f.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                )).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

This gave me full table data, but when I tried to sort based on table2.Name, the sorting did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following way:

```cs
IQueryable<Table1> table1 = _context.Table1;
IQueryable<Table2> table2 = _context.Table2;
IQueryable<Table3> table3 = _context.Table3;
IQueryable<Table4> table4 = _context.Table4;

var query = 
  from t1 in table1
  join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id into g
  from t2 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join t3 in table3 on t1.Id equals t3.Id into g
  from t3 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join t4 in table4 on t1.Id equals t4.Id into g
  from t4 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new AllTables
  {
     Table1 = t1,
     Table2 = t2,
     Table3 = t3,
     Table4 = t4
  };
 
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.Table1.Id.ToString() == searchString);
}

//Example for sorting
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "Id":
       query = query.OrderBy(s => s.Table1.Id);
       break;
    case "Name":
       query = query.OrderBy(s => s.Table2.Name);
       break;
}

var AllTableData = await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I had not considered a query syntax expression. I had previously moved the ```query``` above the search string and the sorting, but I received an error after sorting on the last line ```await query.AsNotTracking().ToListAsync()```. I tried your method described above, and get a similar error: "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request."  the LINQ expression.... could not be translated.

Comment: Although i made it finally work without error, I am not sure if it is the "correct" method.
The only way to make it work without error is to do the query as follows:
```AllTableData = query.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(s => s.Table1.Id).toList();```

Comment: Not it is bad. I have updated answer to do LEFT JOIN differently.

Comment: Retested with the join query you updated. Still getting an InvalidOperationException: LINQ expression... could not be translated. What you propose though is much better than what I came up with. One reason why doing the sorting/search as you have it ```query = query.OrderBy(s => s.Table1.Id);``` instead of how I have it in the comment above is that it would allow for doing both a query and a sort, Since I set the query to AllTableData, it would break any sorting after the search.

Comment: I don't know what happened. This query should be easily translatable to the SQL.